# Closed Beta Test Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-console-beta

I initiated Closed Beta Testing and added emails of users interested in participating, making it available for all countries. There are two links provided for users to become testers via the website and Android app. Upon clicking the first link, users are directed to a page where they can join the testing program.
[Via Website Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubXvE.png)
After joining, they are prompted to download the application. However, clicking the download link leads to an error page.
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dblff.png)
The same error occurs when using the link within the Android app. In summary, users can join the testing program but cannot download the application to their devices.

We tried updating the email list for Closed Beta Testing participants and contacted support for assistance. We expected the download links to function correctly after making these adjustments. However, we are still awaiting a response from support, and the download links continue to lead to error pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.